# Open Map Annotation from Selected Row in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a map view in one class with all of my annotations with titles and subtitles.  There is a nav bar button that shows a list of all of those titles and subtitles.  I'm wanting to be able to select a row in the table view and have it open the annotation with the same title in the map view.  Any help?

The only problem I have now is getting the annotation to show when the map view opens.  I know I need to use selectAnnotation: animated: but I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell it to open the annotation with the matching title.

In RSFM (class with map view named worldView) I show the table view like this:

```
- (void)showList
{
    List *list = [[List alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    list.annotations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:worldView.annotations];
    list.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:list animated:YES];
}
```

Here is what I have so far in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in my table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        RSFM *rsfm = [[RSFM alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        NSLog(@"List Annotations Array Count: %d", [annotations count]);

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *cellTitle = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"Cell Title: %@", cellTitle);


        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [annotations count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *stringFromArray = [[annotations objectAtIndex:i]title];
            NSLog(@"Annotations string: %@", stringFromArray);

            if ([cellTitle isEqualToString:stringFromArray])
            {
                RSFM *rsfm = [[RSFM alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                rsfm.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:rsfm animated:YES];

                // [rsfm.worldView selectAnnotation:<#(id<MKAnnotation>)#> animated:YES];
            }
        }

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select a row in the `tableView`, your method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. So you have to use there the `indexPath` to read the data from your model, and get the title.
You could then read all annotations from your `mapView`, using its `annotations` property. In the array that you get, scan the objects until you find the annotation which has the same title. Then you can send your `mapView` the message `selectAnnotation:animated:`, and it will be shown.
Please be aware that there are more clever approaches to this problem, but for a first try it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to get the array of annotations from my map view but the number of items in the array is 0.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RSFM *rsfm = [[RSFM alloc]init];
    
    NSArray *annotations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rsfm.worldView.annotations, nil];
    NSLog(@"Number of annotations: %d", [annotations count]);
}

Comment: I resolved this issue but I'm not quite sure how to look at just the annotation titles.

Comment: I assume you use MKPointAnnotation objects as your annotations. Their superclass MKShape has a property title that you can assign and read.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue but actually ended up deciding to show a detail view of the selected item from the table view instead of showing that annotation on the map.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSLog(@"List Annotations Array Count: %d", [annotations count]);

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellTitle = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    NSString *cellSubtitle = selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [annotations count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *stringFromArray = [[annotations objectAtIndex:i]title];

        if ([cellTitle isEqualToString:stringFromArray])
        {
            id<MKAnnotation> ann = [annotations objectAtIndex:i];
            AnnotationDetailView *detail = [[AnnotationDetailView alloc]init];

            NSLog(@"Cell Title: %@", cellTitle);
            NSLog(@"Cell Title: %@", cellSubtitle);
            detail.latText = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",ann.coordinate.latitude];
            detail.longText = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f", ann.coordinate.longitude];
            detail.annTitle = cellTitle;
            detail.annSub = cellSubtitle;

            detail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        }
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add this to my original post because then it's too long so I'm posting it here.

And here is my table view:

```
#import "List.h"
#import "RSFM.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"

@interface List ()

@end

@implementation List
{
    NSMutableArray *title;
    NSMutableArray *subtitle;
    NSMutableArray *displayItems;
    NSMutableDictionary *marketDictionary;
    NSMutableArray *farmMarkets;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSMutableArray *objects;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    title = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cates Farm", @"Broadbent B & B Foods", @"Cayce's Pumpkin Patch", @"Metcalfe Landscaping", @"Brumfield Farm Market", @"Dogwood Valley Farm", @"Country Fresh Meats & Farmers Market", @"Jim David Meats", @"Trunnell's Farm Market", @"Lovell's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Zook's Produce", @"The Country Barn", @"Poore's Nursery & Farms", @"Just Piddlin Farm", @"Chaney's Dairy Barn & Restaurant", @"Jackson's Orchard & Nursery, Inc.", @"Mammoth Cave Transplants", @"Habegger's Amish Market", @"Kenny's Farmhouse Cheese", @"Dennison's Roadside Market", @"Roberts Family Farm", @"Wooden Farm", @"Lee's Garden Center, Florist & Gift Shop", @"Hinton's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Serenity Farm Alpacas", @"Burton's Nursery & Garden Center", @"Davis Family Farms", @"Heavenly Haven Farm", @"French Valley Farms", @"Cravens Greenhouse", @"Haney's Appledale Farm", @"Hettmansperger's Greenhouse", @"D & F Farms", @"Double Hart Farm", @"Owens Garden Center", @"Hail's Farm", @"Sinking Valley Vineyard & Winery, Inc.", @"Todd's Greenhouse & Florist, LLC", @"McQuerry's Family Farm-Herbs-N-Heirlooms", @"Berea College Farm & Gardens", @"Acres of Land Winery & Restaurant", @"Baldwin Farms", @"Wonder of Life Farm", @"Chateau du Vieux Corbeau Winery/Old Crow Farm Winery", @"Devine's Farm & Corn Maze", @"Williams Country Market", @"Serano Alpacas & Yarns", @"St. Catharine Farm", @"Capture Your Heart Alpacas", @"Ridgeview Greenhouse & Nursery", @"Country Corner Greenhouse & Nursery, Inc", @"Sunny Acres Farm", @"Morrison's Greenhouses", @"George Gagel Farm Market, LLC", @"Thieneman's Herbs & Perennials", @"Tower View Farm & Nursery", @"Gallrein Farms", @"Sweet Home Spun in the Low Dutch Meetinghouse", @"Mulberry Orchard, LLC", @"Gregory Farms", @"Sherwood Acres Beef", @"Bray Orchard & Roadside Market", @"Callis Orchards", @"Bray Fruit", @"Wilson's Nursery", @"Triple J Farm", @"Ayres Family Orchard", @"Michels Family Farm", @"Amerson Farm", @"Bi-Water Farm & Greenhouse", @"Alpine Hills Dairy Tour/Country Pumpkins", @"Blue Ribbon Market", @"Eagle Bend Alpacas Fiber & Gift Shoppe", @"Redman's Farm",@"The Greenhouse in Gertrude", @"Croppers Greenhouse & Nursery", @"McLean's Aerofresh Fruit", @"Julie's Pumpkins", @"Reed Valley Orchard", @"Evans Orchard & Cider Mill", @"Antioch Daylily Garden", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Boyd Orchards", @"Serenity Hill Fiber & Living History Farm", @"Beech Springs Farm Market", @"Yuletide Tree Farm & Nursery", @"Townsend's Sorghum Mill and Farm Market", @"Bramble Ridge Orchard", @"Country Garden Greenhouse", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Black Barn Produce, LLC", @"Imel's Greenhouse", @"Feathered Wing Farm Market", @"Hutton-Loyd Tree Farm", @"Halcomb's Knob, LLC", @"Happy Hollow Farms", @"Reid's Orchard", @"McKinney Farm", @"Crawford Farms", @"Brian T. Guffey Livestock & Produce", @"MeadowBrook Orchards & Farm", @"Rising Sons Home Farm Winery", @"VanMeter Family Farm", nil];

    subtitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hwy 425 Henderson, KY 42420", @"257 Mary Blue Road Kuttawa, KY 42055", @"153 Farmersville Road Princeton, KY 42445", @"410 Princeton Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"3320 Nebo Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"4551 State Route 109N Clay, KY 42404", @"9355 US Hwy 60 W Sturgis, KY 42459",@"350 T. Frank Wathen Rd. Uniontown, KY 42461", @"9255 Hwy 431 Utica, KY 42376", @"22850 Coal Creek Road Hopkinsville, KY 42240", @"Intersection of KY107 & KY117 Herndon, KY   42240", @"112 Britmart Road Elkton, KY 42220", @"5486 Morgantown Road   Russellville, KY 42276", @"10830 S. Morgantown Rd.  Woodburn, KY 42170", @"9191 Nashville Road, Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"1280 Slim Island Road   Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"5394 Brownsville Road Brownsville, KY 42210", @"945 Perrytown Road  Scottsville, KY 42164", @"2033 Thomerson Park Road Austin, KY 42123", @"5824 S. Jackson Hwy. Horse Cave, KY 42749", @"125 Kennedy Road Guston, KY   40142", @"1869 Wooden Lane Elizabethtown, KY 42701", @"1918 Bardstown Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"8631 Campbellsville Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"1380 Frogg Lane Raywick, KY 40060", @"2212 Saloma Road Campbellsville, KY 42718", @"313 Hwy 1464 Greensburg, KY 42743", @"230 Heavenly Lane Columbia, KY 42728", @"1842 N. Main St. Jamestown, KY 42629", @"500 Cedar Hill Road Albany, KY 42602", @"8350 West 80 Nancy, KY 42544-8756", @"3917 N. Hwy 837 Science Hill, KY 42553", @"755 Elihu Rush Branch Road Somerset, KY 42501", @"6550 Cumberland Falls Road Corbin, KY 40701", @"735 Latham Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"Hwy 461, at 3 mile marker Somerset, KY 42503", @"1300 Plato-Vanhook Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"35 Skyline Drive Eubank, KY 42567", @"169 Pine Hill Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"230 N. Main St. Berea, KY 40404", @"2285 Barnes Mill Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"1113 Tates Creek Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"686 Buckeye Road Lancaster, KY 40444", @"471 Stanford Avenue Danville, KY 40422-1927", @"623 Talmage-Mayo Road Harrodsburg, KY 40330", @"4189 Craintown Rd. Gravel Switch, KY 40328", @"1805 Booker Road Springfield, KY 40069", @"2645 Bardstown Road Springfield, KY 40061", @"9430 Bloomfield Road Bloomfield, KY 40008", @"460 Buffalo Run Road Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"4877 Hwy 44E Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"6516 Echo Trail Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"5613 Cooper Chapel Road Louisville, KY 40229", @"2400 Lower Hunters Trace Louisville, KY 40216", @"9120 Blowing Tree Road Louisville, KY 40220", @"12523 Taylorsville Road Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"1029 Vigo Road Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"6805 Castle Hwy. Pleasureville, KY 40057", @"1330 Mulberry Pike Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"985 Vance Road Turners Station, KY 40075", @"215 Parker Drive LaGrange, KY 40031", @"2580 Hwy 42 W. Bedford, KY 40006", @"3721 Hwy 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"1660 Highway 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"3690 East-West Connector (Rte 676) Frankfort, KY 40601", @"2287 Long Lick Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"525 Wilson Lane Owenton, KY 40359", @"4275 Hwy 1316 Sparta, KY 41086", @"130 McClelland Circle Georgetown, KY 40324", @"877 Cincinnati Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"2165 Sherman Mount Zion Rd. Dry Ridge, KY 41035", @"8707 Camp Ernst Road Union, KY 41091", @"7812 East Bend Road Burlington, KY 41005", @"12449 Decoursey Pike Morning View, KY 41063", @"3246 Augusta-Berlin Road Brooksville, KY 41004", @"5350 Raymond Road May's Lick, KY 41055", @"4085 Ewing Road Ewing, KY 41039", @"1069 Ruddles Mill Road Paris, KY 40361", @"239 Lail Lane Paris, KY 40361", @"180 Stone Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"2231 Houston Antioch Road Lexington, KY 40516", @"1801 Alexandria Drive Lexington, KY 40504", @"1396 Pinckard Pike Versailles, KY 40383", @"1371 Beverly Lane Nicholasville, KY 40356", @"4776 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"3925 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"11620 Main Street Jeffersonville, KY 40337", @"2726 Osborne Road Mt. Sterling, KY 40353", @"99 Union Road Beattyville, KY 41311", @"1523 Hwy 119 North Whitesburg, KY 41815", @"52 KY Route 3224 River, KY 41254", @"2836 State Route 1 Greenup, KY 41144", @"45 Katherine Lane Greenup, KY 41144", @"1483 Big Run Road Wallingford, KY 41093", @"430 Wallacetown Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"9730 KY 136W Calhoun, KY 42327", @"4818 Hwy 144 Owensboro, KY 42303", @"88 Noe Lane Russellville, KY 42276", @"59 Williams Cemetery Rd. Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"1114 KY Hwy 829 Albany, KY 42602", @"680 Dug Hill Rd. Elk Horn, KY 42733", @"975 Frankfort Rd. Lawrenceburg, KY 40342", @"164 Old Peonia Loop Clarkson, KY 42726", nil];

    // searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for name or address";

    farmMarkets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [title count]; i++)
    {
        [farmMarkets addObject: @{@"title" : [title objectAtIndex:i], @"subtitle" : [subtitle objectAtIndex:i]}];
    }

    displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:farmMarkets];

    // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

/*
- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[[note userInfo]objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;
    [tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];
}

- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [tableView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
}
*/

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return [title count];
    return [displayItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // static NSString *mbTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    static NSString *marketListIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellImage.png"];

    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];
        // cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];
        // cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    // cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    // cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:14.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.backgroundView = image;

    // NSLog(@"cell separator style: %d separator color: %@", tableView.separatorStyle, tableView.separatorColor);

    cell.textLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"subtitle"];

    DTCustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:cell.textLabel.textColor];
    accessory.highlightedColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.accessoryView =accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:title];
    }
    else
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        for (NSString *string in title)
        {
            NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [displayItems addObject:string];
            }
        }
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you please focus to the problem? We cannot debug your whole program.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to go about opening the annotation in the map view that has the same title has the selected cell in the table view.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to just give me the answer but I would like some help.